# Sub-Band Extraction Techniques for Complex (I/Q) Signal

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, signal-detection, digital-filters, spectrum-estimation

There is an application which processes Complex I/Q signal of 100 MHz bandwidth and it is required to extract independent sub-bands from this bandwidth at different center frequencies and bandwidths. I wanted to ask what are the techniques which can be used to extract this sub-band data?

Edit: FFT can also be considered as a filter bank. Can the FFT information be used to create independent sub-band data using IFFT etc.?

Comment: I don't know what IQ signal is but I think a set of [filter bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bank) can solve your problem.

Comment: @ZRHan Thanks for your response. I meant the signal is complex (In-Phase and Quadrature component). I also had the idea of filter banks in mind but was wondering if there are other methods as well.

Comment: Another idea is a frequency translation followed by a CIC decimation with a compensation FIR. Can you share what's your application?

Comment: @gotchi85 Thanks for your response, yes I think DDC can also be used for this purpose however how would that scale if a large number of channels are required e.g 50?

Comment: 50 DDC implemented inside an ADC+FPGA is possible. Another possible solution can be an acquisition board + PC + GPU. As always, implementation complexity depends of the spec

Comment: @gotchi85 Is there an FFT based solution as well?

Comment: I've never tried FFT for subbands. Google seems to say yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to ask what are the techniques which can be used to extract this sub-band data?

That's a description of a filter bank.

Yes, the FFT can be used for such applications. You'll find that OFDM, which powers DVB-T, 4G/5G, WiFi, … (basically all high-speed wireless terrestrial links) does exactly that.

You'll also find that if you find the inherent sinc-shape of subcarriers in an FFT filterbank insufficient, but still need regularly spaced channels, polyphase filterbanks are the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am relatively new to this area. Do the polyphase filter banks also perform sample rate conversion or would I need DDCs at the filter bank output for that purpose?

Comment: you can research that yourself within minutes.